# Match and print all words matching some pattern in a long string

Tags: regex, sed, grep

My text file has the following lines (actually much longer):

```
U-what's-WORD|C U--PW|C U-you-NW|C U-what's--W-PW|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C
U-timothy-WORD|C U--PW|C U-green-NW|C U-timothy--W-PW|C

U-life-WORD|C U-odd-PW|C U--NW|C U-life-odd-W-PW|C
U-green-PW|C U-life-NW|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C U-odd-green-W-PW|C

U-green-xxxxk-DISJP-CS|C U-timothy-xxxxk-DISJP-CS|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ1|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C
```

I would like to print all words that contain ``GAZ'' only. If a line does not contain any such words, print empty line.

I tried to search with grep but it matches and prints the whole lines. I tried to use capturing groups (\b.*P.*\b) with boundaries in sed and print that group \1 to no avail.

EDIT
A straightforward approach (which I don't want to implement, yet) is to write a python script. The script will work line by line:

1. tokenize the string using whitespace delimiter
2. match each token to the pattern P and print it if there is a match
3. if there is no match in the whole line, just print blank line

Comment: So you just want to print all the words with `P`?

Comment: @hwnd, Yes, I want to print all the words which match the P pattern. All the other words should be removed (if seen from this perspective)

Comment: @hwnd it matches and prints only P. Moreover, the lines without words matching P are not printed as empty lines.

Comment: use `-o` paramter in grep to print only the match instead of a whole line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used the -o parameter with grep. It prints just P, not the whole word. The P is a substring that I use to match the words I want to print.

Comment: Try `grep -Po '\b\w*P\w*\b'`

Comment: @hwnd Still, it does not match the whole word. I am using GNU grep 2.6.3, perhaps this is the issue.

Comment: with gnu grep 2.5.1 `man grep | grep -o "\w*ff\w*"` gives all words with ff

Comment: @ff The issue remains the same, it prints only the P with some additional character. My pattern P includes "-" and "|".

Comment: try egrep. anyway it will not give you blank lines for mismatches.

Comment: please add some real input, pattern and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints any word in a line which matches pattern `P`.  If no word is found, a blank line is printed:

```
$ awk -v P=GAZ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~P)printf "%s ",$i; print ""}' file
U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C 



U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C 

U-PROGRAM-GAZ1|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C
```

#### How it works

- `-v P=GAZ`

  This defines pattern `P`.  `P` may be a regular expression.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ P) printf "%s ",$i`

  This loops through each word on the line.  If that word matches pattern `P` (`P` may be a regex), then that word is printed.
- `print ""`

At the end of each line, whether there was a match or not, a newline is printed.

Comment: Thanks! Almost what I wanted to achieve! The only change to make: if there are more than one match in the same line, just print the matching words one after another in one line (separate them with a space).

Comment: @xeon That is actually simpler.  Answer updated for same-line printing of multiple matches.

Comment: No need for `{}` around the `printf`, since its only one command: `awk -v P=GAZ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~P)printf "%s ",$i;print ""}'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that a "word" is a sequence of non-whitespace. The key here is the `-o` option to grep that only prints what the regex matches, not the whole line.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -oP '\S*GAZ\S*' <<< "$line" | tr '\n' ' '
    echo 
done < file
```

```
U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C 



U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C 

U-PROGRAM-GAZ1|C U-PROGRAM-GAZ|C
```

Comment: Actually, don't need `-P`: `grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*GAZ[^[:blank:]]*'`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*/ & /;s/ /  /g;s/GAZ/³/g;s/ [^ ³]\{1,\} / /g;s/³/GAZ/g;s/  */ /;s/.\(.*\)./\1/' YourFile
```

- For posix sed (where no *not this group* regex available)
- Assume there is no `³` in string (could use other temporary char or add an escaping sequence, a bit heavier)

**Principe:**

- remove group with no GAZ on the line
- because GAZ could not be an exclude selection, replace `GAZ` by `³` and exclude `³` that is a single univoq char class exclusion, put back  `GAZ` after.
- adapt string for easier selection (add a space at start and end, double space) and reformat at the end